How to get equations and picture side by side?
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Example}
{Evaluate the limit using the graph on the right.}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
   \end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
\end{minipage}%



\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, center]{graph1.PNG}
\end{minipage}



\end{document}

The output looks like this. How can I make the picture side by side to the equations? 

Hi, welcome. The blank lines between the two mini pages generate a paragraph break. Remove them. And start the paragraph before the first minipage with \noindent...

I'd use aligned inside \[...\] (or equation* which is the same) with a Knuthian trick for obtaining flush left and flush right in the display.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Example}

Evaluate the limit using the graph on the right.
\[
\hspace{0pt}
\begin{aligned}
  & \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
  & \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
  & \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
  & \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
\end{aligned}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\displaywidth,valign=c]{example-image}
\]

\end{document}


The \hspace{1000pt minus 1fil} part makes TeX into thinking that the display is really very wide; with the \hspace{0pt} a rule about displays is overridden and so the middle glue can do its job (shrinking so the display actually fits).
If you use \hspace{\parindent} instead of \hspace{0pt} you get


Here is a paracol colution.  And yes, paracol can handle unequal column widths.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Example}
{Evaluate the limit using the graph on the right.}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\null\vfil% vertically center contents
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=\\
   \end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
\switchcolumn
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, center]{example-image}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}

